# R How to convert a numeric into factor with predefined labels

Tags: r, r-factor

```
labs = letters[3:7]
vec = rep(1:5,2)
```

How do I get a factor whose levels are "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
labs = letters[3:7]
vec = rep(1:5,2)
factorVec <- factor(x=vec, levels=sort(unique(vec)), labels = c( "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"))
```

I have sorted the `unique(vec)`, so as to make results consistent. `unique()` will return unique values based on the first occurrence of the element. By specifying the order, the code becomes more robust.

Also by specifying the levels and labels both, I think that code will become more readable.

**EDIT**

If you look in the documentation using `?factor`, you will find :

**levels**
*an optional vector of the values (as character strings) that x might have         taken. The default is the unique set of values taken by as.character(x), sorted into increasing order of x. Note that this set can be specified as smaller than sort(unique(x))*

So you can note that there is some sorting inside the factor faction itself. But it is my opinion that one should add the levels information, so as to make code more readable.

Comment: hmm... How about just `factor(vec, labels = labs)`?

Comment: Which element of lab is assigned to which element in the original vector, will not be clear if levels are not specified. In my work, I had done this error and become wiser after being caught red-handed, when my superior caught this error of mine.

Comment: Kumar, thanks for the help. I agree that seeing both 'levels' and 'labels' would have spared me the confusion that brought me into asking this rather basic question to begin with, but (surprisingly?) in the solution of David Arenburg the labeling is sorted out all right, even if you mess up 'vec' so that the first appearances of unique values is NOT sorted.